# Google Analytics Integration with salesforce

Tags: community, force.com-sites, google-analytics

I Need to track the origin of the pages. ie from which page its navigated to the current page, whether the page is browsed by clicking on a link in the mail etc.

​Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have released the first version of our package. Please install our package from the below link.

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/gallery/#posts/search/%3F_.term%3DGoogle%20Analytics%20for%20Salesforce%20Communities%26_.start%3D0/